# tooltip is set but not displayed in firefox, javascript

Tags: javascript

Can any body please help me why the tooltip is not getting displayed in firefox when it is set using title attribute for `<a>` element while it works with InternetExplorer.
title is set but still not getting displayed.

Comment: Can you post the full markup for your mentioned `<a>` tag?

Also, did you try checking it on another firefox installation?

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-title) does not specify what the browser behavior for setting the `title` attribute on the `a` element should be.

The makers of IE decided to display a tooltip, the makers of Firefox didn't, in early versions.

You can see that in a current version of Firefox, tooltips work as you expect if you hover over the names in the comments on this site.

From the spec:

> This attribute offers advisory information about the element for which it is set.

And:

> Values of the title attribute may be rendered by user agents in a variety of ways. For instance, visual browsers frequently display the title as a "tool tip"

As you can see, the tooltip is not mandated, only suggested as an example.

Comment: Didn't they? Then why my firefox shows a tooltip when I mouseover my username, here for example --->